# Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved error in multi module project

Tags: android, gradle

So I have 3 modules

- module `:commons:ui` which contains `BaseFragment`
- module `:features:home` which contains `HomeFragment`, implements `:commons:ui`
- module `:app` which contains `MainActivity`, implements `:features:home`

now if I try to run `MainActivity` using the following code in `onCreate`

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragment())
    .commit()
```

I get the error

```
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required 
dependencies in the classpath:
class tech.vrutal.home.HomeFragment, unresolved supertypes: tech.vrutal.ui.BaseFragment
```

But if I use **Navigation Component** as follows (removing fragmentManager code in MainActivity)

```
// activity_main.xml

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

// nav_graph.xml

<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:name="tech.vrutal.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment" />

</navigation>
```

now it works as expected

so why creating `HomeFragment()` directly in `MainActivity` fails, while using **Navigation Component** just works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing this problem in a very similar module architecture.

I solved this issue by changing the dependency declaration in `:features:home` 's `build.gradle` file

from

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation project(":commons:ui")
    //...
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    //...
    api project(":commons:ui")
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error many many times in a day. I don't know the cause or how to resolve it, but every time I try to run the app for the second time, it works.